# How to send event from custom linear layout to child view

Tags: android, gridview, android-linearlayout, multi-touch

I have a custom linearlayout in which I have two gridviews.
I want to have multitouch on the complete linearlayout, ie, first touch can be in one gridview and second touch can be in another gridview and the linear layout should be able to get multitouch events for this (ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_POINTER_DOWN). I am able to get this by overriding onInterceptTouchEvent in my custom layout.
Now I also want the gridview to scroll independently if required. Although gridview is a scrollable view, it is not able to do so, because I have intercepted the 'down' event. I see that when I try to scroll two events are generated : 'ACTION_DOWN' and 'ACTION_MOVE'. 
Since I need ACTION_DOWN for multitouch use case I want it to be sent to linearlayout as well.

Is there a possibility to send the ACTION_DOWN event to both the linearlayout as well as my child view which is gridView in this case?

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to **intercept** `ACTION_DOWN` just to monitor that it flowed through your container view.  In other words, you can override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to monitor the touch events before they are passed to the appropriate child view by the framework, but as long as you don't screw with the return value it won't actually steal subsequent touch events from the grid elements.  For example:

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)
    if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        //Touchdown!
    }

    //Don't modify this and touch interaction will happen normally
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

This allows you to see the event without taking it away from the child element(s).